# Azure deployment - what the difference between angular hosting as static files in azure storage vs web app with nodejs?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops

I want to deploy my angular app on azure. 
As i understood, there are two options:
1. As static files in azure storage 
2. Behide nodejs as webapp

What the difference between them?

Thanks

Comment: Azure storage probably provides built-in features like CDN which can really help with performance of loading static assets. If it’s really a static angular site, do you need a server for anything?

Comment: We have different server for all api requests. So i just uploaded all the dist folder. Btw, what is the main purpose of the cdn?

Comment: That’s a question too broad for the scope of this platform. I’d recommend starting with doing some research about CDNs including the benefits. If you still have questions, you can create a new question with the specific issue you are experiencing. At a basic level, it’s great for static content overall, just keep in mind avoid caching of service worker file otherwise you will experience issues pushing updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary difference is the webapp provides you dedicated hosting capacity that is really not used since the Angular app will run entirely on the client.  The Web App offers a number of additional features including server side identity and others that are not offered through the static websites.  One thing you can't do with a static website is specify the content security policies or modify the response headers for security issues.

I wrote this article when static websites were first released that talks through some of the features and some interesting things you can do with Function App Proxies.
https://www.deliveron.com/blog/serverless-websites-azure-new-storage-account-static-websites/